# Εrror message ata3:COMRESET failed (errno=-16) during startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed to my HDD Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop (Lenovo G500 i7-3612QM). After a month using the laptop with dual boot sometimes when i try to boot into Ubuntu i encounter this error message. I searched the web and i found that many other users had this issue.

I also notice that when i encounter this issue and then i boot to Windows , sometimes my laptop will freeze out and it will be ok again after some minutes. From the event viewer i understand that I/0 from HDD during the freezing has also froze (I mean that OS was waiting from HDD to respond and because the HDD didn't respond and the OS froze).

**My question is:** Is my disk dying or is the dual-boot installation the source of the problem ?

(I have made disk checks and the disk seems fine but i am not so sure)

Comment: What does the `Disks` app `SMART Data & Tests` say about the condition of the drive?

Comment: I have already checked them. No problems.